# Sharepoint second page library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, publishing

Sharepoint 07 has nice page library. You can create templates and then just by pressing Site-> 'Create a page' get a choice with page templates.

However if one tries to create second library, for example, document library, in the same site (node), then it is not possible to choose element type as "page". Only "wiki-pages" and "pages with web-parts"!

So, is it possible to get 2 or more page libraries in the same node?
It seems very inconvenient to create the hole new site or new node only just for page library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure can only handle a single Pages library per Web site, it's a physical limitation of the software.

You could create sub webs to separate out your content more, or create new Content Types inheriting from the "Page" content type, and add in extra columns to store metadata to further categorize your pages. You'd then add this new content type to the Pages library, and you can slot your new content into this content type to categorize it.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, I have discovered another solution. Using Metalogix Content Matrix I was able to copy and paste the 'Page' Library renaming it and Viola...it works! I'm able to edit pages with**out** getting the "The SPListItem provided is not compatible with a Publishing Page" Error. Whohoo! I hope this helps you.